# Isolating client data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

From mongo documentacion:

> The following is the standard URI connection scheme:
>   
>   mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]] 
>  ... 
>   `/database` 
>   Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the connection string includes authentication credentials in the form of username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin database.

Given the connections

- `mongodb://host/db1`
- `mongodb://host/db2`

Its not clear to me

1. On the same host machine, is the data from these two connections  isolated on storage/retrieval?
2. If so, are there benefits to this "namespacing".
3. If not, what is the purpose of the `/database` parameter?

Comment: Voted to close as this is off topic. The aspect of the inner workings belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com (where I will gladly answer this question after it is migrated), the other parts are only loosely related to programming, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

The same *data server* (i.e. an instance of mongodb running, listening on a port) can host multiple *databases*. In the context of those connections, each database is identified by its name.

Those databases can be multiple instances of the same schema (a "conceptual" schema that is, because mongodb doesn't use schemas), or be completely different.

As to Q1: Yes, storage of different databases is separate.

Comment: Is there a penalty for each extra *database*?